# how to properly plot igraph's graphs to make them comparable?

Tags: r, plot, igraph

So, as in the title, I need to be able to plot some igraph's graphs and be able to compare them. To do so I believed that passing coordinates and then plotting them was enough. Then I found out that the graphs are rendered according to the coordinates that are provided but also according to the number of nodes (or the number of subnetworks or whatever other parameter which I am not able to understand). In order to get a grasp over the problem here is an example (the part related to euclidean distance is commented since it require a specific package, but I also posted the output):

```
library(igraph)
#library(TSdist)

smallNet <- graph(edges=c(1,2), n=2, directed=F) 

V(smallNet)$name <- c("mint", "pepper")

# first try
dev.new()

V(smallNet)$x <- c(10, 23)
V(smallNet)$y <- c(29, 36)

plot(smallNet, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", vertex.size=40, vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely)
#print(paste("distance ", EuclideanDistance(V(smallNet)$x, V(smallNet)$y)))
#[1] "distance  23.0217288664427"


# second try
dev.new()

V(smallNet)$x <- c(1400, 1894)
V(smallNet)$y <- c(3700, 4140)

plot(smallNet, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", vertex.size=40, vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely)
#print(paste("distance ", EuclideanDistance(V(smallNet)$x, V(smallNet)$y)))
#[1] "distance  3214.73420363177"

# third try
dev.new()

V(smallNet)$x <- c(10000, 26230)
V(smallNet)$y <- c(13800, 32150)

plot(smallNet, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", vertex.size=40, vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely)
#print(paste("distance ", EuclideanDistance(V(smallNet)$x, V(smallNet)$y)))
#[1] "distance  7034.65706342534"
```

The point is that the (euclidean) distances are different but, if I look at the plots, nothing **apparently** changes. On the other hand, **something** must be different since the node's distance is increasing.

I noticed that adding few nodes improves the visualisation but still I believe the plots I am getting are not, somehow, respecting the actual distances. Here's another sample code with more nodes:

```
# first try
evenBigger <- graph(edges=c(1,2, 2,3, 3,1, 4,5), n=5, directed=F) 

V(evenBigger)$name <- c("pear", "mango", "blueberry", "coconut", "fig")

dev.new()

V(evenBigger)$x <- c(0, 25, 50, 70, 60)
V(evenBigger)$y <- c(0, 80, 20, 120, 40)

plot(evenBigger, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", vertex.size=40, vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely)

# second try
evenBigger <- graph(edges=c(1,2, 2,3, 3,1, 4,5, 6,6), n=6, directed=F) 

V(evenBigger)$name <- c("pear", "mango", "blueberry", "coconut", "fig", "jujube")

dev.new()

V(evenBigger)$x <- c(0, 25, 50, 70, 120, 2000)
V(evenBigger)$y <- c(0, 80, 20, 120, 140, 2000)

plot(evenBigger, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", vertex.size=40, vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely)
```

it looks like in these two new examples, **something** changes, since the **jujube** node is now far away, if compared to the other nodes. Are now the two nets comparable, from a graphical perspective? If not (which I believe to be the case)...what should I do in order to make them comparable?

I tried to set xlim and ylim as mentioned [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/igraph/versions/1.2.4.1/topics/plot.igraph) but it looks like it is not working:

```
# first try
evenBigger <- graph(edges=c(1,2, 2,3, 3,1, 4,5), n=5, directed=F) 

V(evenBigger)$name <- c("pear", "mango", "blueberry", "coconut", "fig")

dev.new()

V(evenBigger)$x <- c(0, 25, 50, 70, 60)
V(evenBigger)$y <- c(0, 80, 20, 120, 40)

plot(evenBigger, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", vertex.size=40, vertex.color="thistle1", xlim=c(0, 2500), ylim=c(0, 2500), layout=layout_nicely)

# second try
evenBigger <- graph(edges=c(1,2, 2,3, 3,1, 4,5, 6,6), n=6, directed=F) 

V(evenBigger)$name <- c("pear", "mango", "blueberry", "coconut", "fig", "jujube")

dev.new()

V(evenBigger)$x <- c(0, 25, 50, 70, 120, 2000)
V(evenBigger)$y <- c(0, 80, 20, 120, 140, 2000)

plot(evenBigger, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", vertex.size=40, vertex.color="thistle1", xlim=c(0, 2500), ylim=c(0, 2500), layout=layout_nicely)
```

Suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

igraph plotting  does some rescaling that leads to this kind of non-intuitive output. You can see this by turning on the axes. Here I will do that for your "second try"

```
### Second try
V(smallNet)$x <- c(1400, 1894)
V(smallNet)$y <- c(3700, 4140)
plot(smallNet, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", 
    vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely,
    axes=TRUE, main="Second Try")
```

[image: Second try with axes]

Notice that even though you placed the points at (x,y) = (1400,3700) and (1894, 4140), they are plotted at (-1,-1) and (1,1).   igraph automatically rescales both x and y to the interval [-1,1]. You can turn this of with the `rescale` parameter. However,  doing so requires other changes. Even if you turn off rescaling, igraph assumes that the plot interval is [-1,1] for both x and y. You need to change xlim and ylim. Also, the node size is in units on the graph and so must be proportional to the range of the data.   I put all of these into:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

# first try
V(smallNet)$x <- c(10, 23)
V(smallNet)$y <- c(29, 36)
plot(smallNet, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", 
    vertex.size=8*diff(range(V(smallNet)$x)), 
    vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely, 
    xlim=range( V(smallNet)$x), ylim=range( V(smallNet)$y),
    rescale=FALSE, axes=TRUE, main="First Try")

# second try
V(smallNet)$x <- c(1400, 1894)
V(smallNet)$y <- c(3700, 4140)
plot(smallNet, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", 
    vertex.size=8*diff(range(V(smallNet)$x)), 
    vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely,
    xlim=range( V(smallNet)$x), ylim=range( V(smallNet)$y),
    rescale=FALSE, axes=TRUE, main="Second Try")

# third try
V(smallNet)$x <- c(10000, 26230)
V(smallNet)$y <- c(13800, 32150)
plot(smallNet, vertex.label.color="midnightblue", 
    vertex.size=8*diff(range(V(smallNet)$x)), 
    vertex.color="thistle1", layout=layout_nicely, 
    xlim=range( V(smallNet)$x), ylim=range( V(smallNet)$y),
    rescale=FALSE, axes=TRUE, main="Third Try")
```

[image: All three graphs without rescaling]

Now you can see that, even though the shape is similar, they are on different scales.

Comment: It works, thanks. Only a quick question: I see your point in saying that the size of the nodes should be scaled according to the plot but why are you multiplying the size by 8? I believe is something you chose and is not related to anything specific...am I right?

Comment: Correct. I chose 8 times the range because it looked OK.